# No se muestra input en servlet java

Tags: java, jsp, jpql

¿Por qué no se muestra el input en el servlet? Es solo cuando lo añado detras de de un for, si no lo muestro detrás de un for se me muestra sin problema, no sé si me falta algo por añadir en el html o cual es el problema

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

      String empleado = request.getParameter("nombre");
      Empleado emple = new Empleado(empleado);

       try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
       List<Historial> his = incidenciasEJB.findMaxHistorialEmpleado(emple);

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>ServletMostrarUltimoInicio</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");         

       int maxId = incidenciasEJB.findMaxHistorial();



       if(!incidenciasEJB.existeEmpleado(emple)){

            out.println("<p>No existe el empleado de destino "+ empleado+"</p>");

              out.println("<form action=\"index.jsp\" method=\"POST\">"
                + "Volver a la pagina principal  "
                + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"volver\" value=\"VOLVER\" />"
                + "</form>");
       }else{

           out.println("ULTIMO INICIO DE SESIÓN DEL EMPLEADO "+empleado.toUpperCase() );
      for(int i=0; i<maxId;i++){

            out.print("<p><b>ID: </b>" + 
                   his.get(i).getIdevento() +
                    ", <b>Fecha hora: </b>" + 
                    his.get(i).getFechahora()+
                    ", <b>Tipo: </b>" +
                    his.get(i).getTipo()  +                     
                     " <b>Empleado: </b>" +               
                    his.get(i).getEmpleado().getNombreusuario() +"</p><br>");

        }
             out.println("<form action=\"index.jsp\" method=\"POST\">"
                + "Volver a la pagina principal  "
                + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"volver\" value=\"VOLVER\" />"
                + "</form>");
       }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no existe el empleado si que se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En el código que insertas, solo va a mostrar el mensaje cuando el método "existeEmpleado" devuelva True, ya que en la sentencia IF compruebas si es falso y el formulario lo estás imprimiendo dentro del else. En primer lugar, yo revisaría lo que devuelve el método "existeEmpleado". Si quieres, muestralo por pantalla en el mismo formulario (haz un print de su valor).Luego, para que ese enlace te aparezca siempre, sácalo fuera del ámbito del else.

```
if(!incidenciasEJB.existeEmpleado(emple)){

        out.println("<p>No existe el empleado de destino "+ empleado+"</p>");

          out.println("<form action=\"index.jsp\" method=\"POST\">"
            + "Volver a la pagina principal  "
            + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"volver\" value=\"VOLVER\" />"
            + "</form>");
   }else{

       out.println("ULTIMO INICIO DE SESIÓN DEL EMPLEADO "+empleado.toUpperCase() );
  for(int i=0; i<maxId;i++){

        out.print("<p><b>ID: </b>" + 
               his.get(i).getIdevento() +
                ", <b>Fecha hora: </b>" + 
                his.get(i).getFechahora()+
                ", <b>Tipo: </b>" +
                his.get(i).getTipo()  +                     
                 " <b>Empleado: </b>" +               
                his.get(i).getEmpleado().getNombreusuario() +"</p><br>");

    }//**FIN DEL FOR**
         out.println("<form action=\"index.jsp\" method=\"POST\">"
            + "Volver a la pagina principal  "
            + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"volver\" value=\"VOLVER\" />"
            + "</form>");
   }//**FIN DEL ELSE**
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}
```

Comment: buenas, gracias por contestar. Aunque lo saque fuera del else ubicándolo justo encima de out.println("</body>")  se comporta exactamente igual

Comment: ¿Puedes volver a pegar el código modificado?